# Is a function obtained from some L2 function by fixing some of its variables again in L2?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lie-groups, haar-measure

Lets take a complex-valued function $f\in L^{2}(G^{d},\mathbb{C})$, where $G$ is some compact Lie group and where the $L^{2}$-space has to be understood with respect to the normalized Haar measure on $d$-copies of the group. By definition, $f$ fulfills

$$\Vert f\Vert_{L^{2}}^{2}=\int_{G^{d}}\,\bigg (\prod_{i=1}^{d}\mathrm{d}g_{i}\bigg )\,\vert f(g_{1},\dots,g_{d})\vert^{2}<\infty$$

where $\mathrm{d}g_{i}$ is just a short-hand notation for the (normalized) Haar measure with respect to the ith variable. Normalized here means that $\int\mathrm{d}g_{i}=1$ for all $i$. If I define a function $g$ via

$$g(g_{1},g_{2},g_{3}):=f(g_{1},\dots,g_{d})$$

for some fixed values $g_{4},\dots,g_{d}$, is it then true that $g\in L^{2}(G^{3},\mathbb{C})$? I tried several times to find some estimates, but I was not able to prove it.

By definition, we have that

$$\Vert g\Vert_{L^{2}}^{2}=\int_{G^{3}}\,\bigg (\prod_{i=1}^{3}\mathrm{d}g_{i}\bigg )\,\vert f(g_{1},\dots,g_{d})\vert^{2}$$

but I am not sure how I can "insert" the integration for the other variables..

Comment: This should be true for a.e. $g_4,\dots,g_d$

Comment: Okay, to you know how to prove it? "Almost every" would be fine for my specific purpose, in the end I am interested in integrating $\Vert g\Vert_{L^{2}}^{2}$ over all these elements $g_{4},\dots,g_{d}$, if my question turns out to be true.

Comment: Integrating over the remaining variables just gets you back to $\|f\|_{L^2}^2$ which is finite. If $\|g\|_{L^2}^2$ were infinite on a set of nonzero measure then using Fubini's theorem $\|f\|_{L^2}^2$ could not be finite.

Comment: $L^2$-spaces are most often defined as the set of square-integrable functions quotiented by the kernel of the $L^2$-norm. In this definition, the restriction to a set of measure zero is not even well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. Consider

$$ f(x,y) = \frac{e^{-y^2e^{2x^2}}}{x^2 + 1}.$$

This is less than $ e^{-y^2e^{2x^2}} $, which is an $L^2$ function since its square integral with respect to y with x fixed is at most some constant proportion of $ e^{-x^2} $ (via the Gaussian integral), whose integral converges.

But if you fix $y = 0$, the function with respect to $x$ is proportional to a Cauchy distribution.

This counterexample is over $\mathbb{R}^2$, but you should be able to construct an analogous counterexample for a compact Lie group: just have the function’s square integral diverge in the first 3 variables for a specific choice of the other variables, but converge for all other choices and decay sufficiently fast in those other variables so that the whole thing is still $L^2$.

Comment: I don't think that one can construct a similar example for a compact Lie group. In the end, the divergency in your case is due to $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\infty$, which is not the case for the normalized Haar measure.

Comment: You're right, but I was imagining a divergence from integrating a vertical asymptote for the compact Lie group. For example, $\int_{-1}^1 1/|x| \mathrm{d}x = \infty$ suggests using $e^{-y^2e^{2x^2}/x^2}/\sqrt{|x|}$ as the counterexample. I should've made that explicit, yes.